# Cannot create partition on ubuntu 14

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I have some issues installing ubuntu 14 from cd along with win7. I left some free space on hard drive (~50GB) on windows and started booting ubuntu. Everything went well untill I realised ubuntu don't recognize partitions. It's okay, because I left a free space though. But I can't even create new partition from ubuntu. I opened Disks manager on ubuntu and I can see all the partitions and that 50gb unallocated space. When I try to create partition there I get a message:

```
Error creating partition:
Error creating partition on /dev/sda: Command-line `parted --align optimal --script "/dev/sda" "mkpart primary ext2 903869MiB 1000204886015b"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Warning: /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.  Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
Error: You requested a partition from 948GB to 1000GB.
The closest location we can manage is 948GB to 1000GB.
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

I am able to read the stack trace and what happens but it does not make sens to me. How can it contains GPT signatures as it's not even a partition but just a free space. And if apparently it does, how to remove the so I can simply create ext4 partition?

Comment: MSDOS partition type only allows 4primary partitions. How many do you already have?

Comment: 3 partitions and 50gb free memory

Answer (score 0):

The default install needs two partitions, a root and a swap.  You have room for only one more primary, so you need to put all the free space on the disk into an "extended" partition (a type of primary).  This extended partition can then hold additional partitions called "logical partitions", so the installer can make what it needs.